# Eclipse for PHP Code Assistant not working

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Luna (4.4.0) for PHP Developers. The code assistant doesn't work at all. Text hovers won't show the documentation even for basic PHP commands. I can't navigate through functions and classes via "open declaration" option either.
PDT (3.3.0) is installed.

Does anyone knows anything about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have problems with code assistant for new projects created with eclipse luna, but I have issues with older projects that I have created with previous versions of eclipse.

For problems with code assistant for basic PHP commands, check your buildpath entries in '.buildpath' file, and make sure that following line is present:

```
<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
```

For problems with code assistant for you classes, functions you can try to delete files under:

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2
```

for more info visit https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/489559/.

Comment: Worked for me too!